# Are the values of pi and e available in the .Net framework?

Tags: .net, math, constants

Without [calculating them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19/fastest-way-to-get-value-of-pi), I mean?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
System.Math.PI;
System.Math.E;
```