# Does the .net framework have a build-in method to convert from degrees to radians?

Tags: .net, math

I know that I can just say:

```
radians  = degrees * Math.PI/180
```

However I expect there to be a built in framework method, as it is such a common requirement, however I cannot find one.    Am I not looking hard enough or is it missing from the .net framework.

*(Please don’t insult me by telling me how to write my own method.)*

Comment: I don't know of any, and I have been doing quite a lot of math in .NET. I must be careful not to put ToDegrees() or ToRadians() methods all over the place...

Comment: I happen to have my own strut to hold degree values (so I can wrap at 360), so I only need to put the method in one place.

Comment: I dont know why there is a downvote when the question is so clear and has a need

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the method for converting radians to degrees?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135909/what-is-the-method-for-converting-radians-to-degrees)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe there is no such method.

> The angle, a, must be in radians. Multiply by Math.PI/180 to convert
>   degrees to radians.

Above quote taken from [Math.Sin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.sin.aspx) remarks section.

If there is one method in .Net framework, documentation would suggest us to use that rather than giving the formula to implement.

Comment: In general, the Math class of .NET is very basic, just a copy of the old <math.h> one knows from C. Maybe the developers of .NET were not very eager to do more complex math? If anything more sophisticated is needed, a math library is unavoidable.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no built in functionality in the Framework (did the same research myself some time ago). I'e gone with your solution.