# Have javascript assume degrees instead of radians?

Tags: javascript, math

My problem is that I have an input field where you type in some degrees and a velocity ( like `44 degrees` and `10m/s`). Then that runs through some javascript, and it spits out a trajectory.

A jsfiddle showing my problem a little better.

http://jsfiddle.net/3ahhf1xL/1/

How do i input it as degrees? or convert radians to the exact same amount of degrees?

Edit: I want to convert it to the same amount of degrees. an example of 44 radians would result in 2521 degrees if I straight up convert them instead of 44 degrees (amount of radians = amount of degrees).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135909/what-is-the-method-for-converting-radians-to-degrees

Comment: Yes, i know that. However that would convert the radians to a different amount of degrees. Example 44 radians to 2521 degrees.

Comment: There is not much research on this question, plus, when posting jsfiddle, is always a good idea to show your code too, in case jsfiddle fails (in the future)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to multiply the degree by `PI/180`.  In JavaScript, it looks like this:

```
var rads = degrees * (Math.PI / 180);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
function toRadians(degrees) {
    return degrees * (Math.PI / 180);
}

function toDegrees(radians) {
    return radians * (180 / Math.PI);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`1 degree` equals `0.0174532925 radians`..

So you can change your code into this:

```
function submit() {
    var a = document.getElementById('var1').value * 0.0174532925;
    var b = document.getElementById('var2').value * 0.0174532925;

    alert(a);

    myGraph.drawEquation(function(x) {
        return x*Math.tan(a)-((9.80665*(x*x))/(2*b^2*Math.cos(a)^2));
    }, 'red', 3);
}
```