# How to calculate heading/direction between two lat, longs with javascript?

Tags: javascript

Assuming I have the following:

Point A (lat, lon)
33.95,-118.4333

Point B (lat, lon)
33.9461,-118.4431

I want to get the angle/direction the line is pointing to.
How do I do this in Javascript?

Comment: `SIN`, `COS`, `ATAN2` are all available natively in JS. This might be helpful regarding degrees and radians: http://stackoverflow.com/q/135909/218196 .

Comment: Check [**this**](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)! It could be of some help!

Answer (score 0):

There's a npm package for that:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/geojson-tools#getDistance

and it's fairly easy to use:

```
const { getDistance } = require('geojson-tools')
var array = [
    [20, 30],
    [20.5, 29.5]
 ];

 getDistance(array, 4); // 76.3212
```

Units are in meters i believe.

If you need the actual code to `getDistance`, you may look for it here: https://github.com/MovingGauteng/GeoJSON-Tools/blob/master/src/geojson-tools.js