# How to convert from K&R C to ANSI C?

Tags: c, obfuscation, kr-c

I am trying to execute following code which is the 1988 entry of Obfuscated C Code Contest.

```
#define _ -F<00||--F-OO--;
int F=00,OO=00;main(){F_OO();printf("%1.3f\n",4.*-F/OO/OO);}F_OO()
{
            _-_-_-_
       _-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_
    _-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_
  _-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_
 _-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_
 _-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_
_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_
_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_
_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_
_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_
 _-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_
 _-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_
  _-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_
    _-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_
        _-_-_-_-_-_-_-_
            _-_-_-_
}
```

From entry description, this code is calculating pi by looking at its own area. I successfully compiled it without changing the code. But when I executed, it is giving me a value 0.25, what I am expecting is 3.14. Code description says it is in K&R C and it doesn't work correctly in ANSI C without some change. I think I have to do those modification to execute it properly. I don't have any previous experience with K&R C. So can someone help me to change above code to ANSI C or point to the problems if any. I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 to execute this.

Comment: For the love of $DEITY, why? I can't see this as being the least bit useful. The obfuscated competitions are fine as a way of showing how "clever" you can be, but they really have little relevance in the real world. My advice, find a real problem and solve it.

Comment: @Pax: +Inf for $DEITY :)

Comment: @Pax: -Inf for infinite blasphemy :)

Comment: So, since when has 'fun' stopped being an acceptable excuse for doing something?  I think it makes a nice change from the "do my job for me" questions of other posters.

Comment: @Pax: Who among us has not been called upon to decipher some horrifying , yet somewhat functional, mess of "cleverness" left behind by a predecessor?  Studying intentionally obfuscated code seems like a prudent form of self-defense -- even more so if it's *genuinely* clever!

Comment: @Pax: Personally I'd prefer $DEITIES, but what the heck... Nontheless I agree with Michiel: 'fun' is on of the greatesd excuses to do something...

Comment: I knew I remembered this problem from before:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/841646/is-define-supposed-to-add-spaces-around-macros

Comment: Removed C++ tag, as the question specifically relates to C.

Answer (score 10):

If you have GCC, compile with the '`-traditional-cpp`' flag.

The difference is whether the '`-_`' sequence is translated to '`- -F<00`' or '`--F<00`'.

The one space is crucial: it's the difference between double negation and pre-decrement.

Comment: Unfortunately, the OP hid their compiler in the last sentence, when most of us (myself included until a couple seconds ago) stop reading. He/She is using VS2008.

Comment: Hats off, sir. I saw the convergence process (the program is not really working "off its own area", the iterations are just arranged in a cute fashion), but this detail in interpreting -_ wow!

Comment: @Chris: I saw the VS2008; I don't have it.  I have my doubts that VS2008 will support the equivalent of -traditional-cpp.  That was why I put the 'if' up front.

Answer (score 2):

change the line:

```
#define _ F-->00 || F-OO--;
```