# How to avoid cpp adding spaces to macro parameters

Tags: c++, gcc, macros

My company has 1000s of source files that use a macro to specify the include path. I cannot change that and it works with the current compilers. Now, I try to compile that with GCC (4.8.2 or 3.4.6) and it fails.

Basically there is a macro like that:

```
#define COMP_INC(comp, file) <comp/include/file>
```

That is used like that:

```
#include COMP_INC(posix, inttypes.h)
```

My problem is that GCC is for some unknown reason translating my macro call into that:

```
#include <posix/include/ inttypes.h>
```

Notice the space before "inttypes.h"? Because of that, the header file is not found.

Why does the preprocessor insert a space? Can I avoid it? I can only change the macro, I cannot change the source files that uses it.

Comment: Just create a file with the macro and the #include that uses it like in my example. And create a file like that: `mkdir -p posix/include; touch posix/include/inttypes.h`

Comment: So how do they normally compile these 1000s of files and why are you not using the same compiler?

Comment: With Intel's C compiler or heavily customized GCC and I'm trying to move to vanilla GCC.

Comment: If this macro is not in a header file, that is a horrible design (besides being a horrible design to need this macro anyway). If it *is* in a header file, `#ifdef` a version for "vanilla" gcc and one for the other.

Comment: @crashmstr: It's in a file pre-loaded with the -imacro option. I won't comment on the design. And the `#ifdef` was my intention, but I cannot find a solution that works with a normal gcc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the space between `posix` and `inttypes.h` (after the comma). The problem goes away.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/841708/2591612) tells us why this occurs:

> From the C99 standard:
>
> A preprocessing directive of the form
>
> # define identifier replacement-list new-line
>
> defines an object-like macro that causes each subsequent instance of the macro name to be 
>     replaced by the replacement list of preprocessing tokens that constitute the remainder of the 
>     directive.
>
> ---
>
> So macros work on tokens and the whitepace is to be expected.

EDIT:

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/841799/2591612), you can use the `traditional-cpp` flag to mimic the old behavior of not adding the space. I am not sure how that will affect your build, but you can try it:

> Only much older preprocessors didn't insert that extra space -- note
>   that original entry was submitted over 20 years ago in 1988, before
>   the 1989 version of the C standard was standardized. You can pass the
>   -traditional-cpp flag to the GCC preprocessor, which causes it to imitate the behavior of old-fashioned C preprocessors, as opposed to
>   ISO C preprocessors.

Comment: Yes, calling the macro without spaces after the coma would solve the problem. But I cannot modify all the files that are using this macro.

Comment: @PatrickValsecchi: I thought you couldn't change the macro, but you could change the include? I am referring to the include.

Comment: It's the correct answer, your assumption is faulty. The preprocessor does not add a space, you put the space there and GCC keeps it.

Comment: @MSalters: There is no way to remove it? With the following, there is no space, but doesn't work for me: `#define COMP_INC(comp, file) <comp/include/a##file>`

Comment: The problem is in the include. I dont know how to strip it in the macro. There is the option to compile with the traditional-cpp flag. Look at the linked answer in my post

Comment: -traditional-cpp sadly works only with the -E option (if you run only the pre-processor). I tried and it's a noop if you compile.

Answer (score 2):

If you can accept to predefine all possible 'comp'-names and 'file'-names:

```
#define MAKE_INCLUDE(comp, file) <comp/include/file>

#define NAME_posix posix
#define NAME_inttypes inttypes

#define MAKE_NAME(x) NAME_##x

#define COMP_INC(comp, file) MAKE_INCLUDE(MAKE_NAME(comp), MAKE_NAME(file))

#include COMP_INC(posix, inttypes.h)
```

Note: A suffix like '.h' can not be part of a macro. Hence, directories like lib-1.0-A and lib-1.0-B will be indistinguishable (but it might be no issue, here).

Comment: Very good idea, but not doable for this project that has more than 60000 header files.

Comment: Patrick, then you are really stuck between a rock and a hard place. We cant help you