# Python efficient vectorization for Monte Carlo based Pi calculation

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, montecarlo, pi

For approximating the value of Pi consider this stochastic method that populates an array with random values and tests for unit circle inclusion,

```
import random as rd
import numpy as np

def r(_): return rd.random()

def np_pi(n):
    v_r = np.vectorize(r)
    x = v_r(np.zeros(n))
    y = v_r(np.zeros(n))

    return sum (x*x + y*y <= 1) * 4. / n
```

Note the random number generation relies on Python standard library; consider though numpy random generation,

```
def np_pi(n):
   x = np.random.random(n)
   y = np.random.random(n)

    return sum (x*x + y*y <= 1) * 4. / n
```

Consider now the non-vectorized approach,

```
import random as rd

def dart_board():
    x,y = rd.random(), rd.random()
    return (x*x + y*y <= 1)

def pi(n):
    s = sum([dart_board() for _ in range(n)])
    return s * 4. / n
```

The non-vectorized form proves 4 times faster in average than the vectorized counterpart, for instance consider `n = 5000000` and OS command line as follows (Python 2.7, Quadcore, 8GB RAM, RedHat Linux),

```
time python pi.py
time python np_pi.py
```

Thus to ask how to improve the vectorized approach to improve its performance.

Comment: Note that using Monte-Carlo methods to calculate pi is [hopelessly inefficient](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18141358/2647279), so it is useless for anything other than demonstrating Monte Carlo techniques. Better to use some sort of [series approximation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PiFormulas.html) if you want a fast method to calculate pi.

Comment: @BasSwinckels fully agree, this was more of a first exploration on numpy and its efficiency.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are invoking the *python builtin* `sum`, rather than numpy's vectorized method `sum`:

```
import numpy as np
import random as rd

def np_pi(n):
    x = np.random.random(n)
    y = np.random.random(n)

    return (x*x + y*y <= 1).sum()

def dart_board():
    x,y = rd.random(), rd.random()
    return (x*x + y*y <= 1)

def pi(n):
    s = sum([dart_board() for _ in range(n)])
```

Timing results are now much different:

```
In [12]: %timeit np_pi(10000)
1000 loops, best of 3: 250 us per loop

In [13]: %timeit pi(10000)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.54 ms per loop
```

It is my guess that calling the builtin `sum` on a numpy-array causes overhead by iterating over the array, rather than using vectorized routines.