# Leibniz formula for π/4

Tags: c, double

I am asked to print the summation of the Leibniz formula up to the nth term of the series correct to 15 decimal places.In Calculus, the Leibniz formula for π is given by:
1 - 1/3 + 1/5 -1/7 + ... = π/4

This is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{
    int n,i;
    long double s=0;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        s+=(long double)pow(-1,i)/(2*i+1);
    }
    printf("%Lf\n",s);
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone tell me why i can't reach precision upto 15th decimal place?
My aim is not to print the value of pi/4, i just have to print the summation for a given n

Comment: What `n` are you entering? Did you read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80#Inefficiency from your link?

Comment: Did you read the `Inefficiency` section of the Wikipedia article you linked to?

Comment: The formula is for π/4. And that particular series converges *very* slowly.

Comment: Did you read http://floating-point-gui.de/ ?

Comment: Also, `long double` mostly the alias for `double`, so it won't give more than 17 significant digits. But that's an other story in this case.

Comment: @m0nhawk: That depends on the implementation. On some systems, `long double` is substantially more precise than `double`.

Comment: You'll have better luck with Manchin's formula.

Comment: You're missing `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <math.h>`; your compiler should have warned you about undeclared functions. `pow` works on `double` values, use `powl` for `long double`. (Not that the extra precision of `long double` is doing you any good in this case anyway.)

Comment: @KeithThompson that's why I put *mostly*, thought, I don't have a statistics what's more popular.

Comment: Check the answer from the holder of [π record](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14283481/1030110). There are pretty fast-convergent equalities for π.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Q: why ... reach precision upto 15th decimal place?
A: To *display* 15 decimal places after the decimal point use format `"%0.15f"`.  To calculate 15 decimal places of convergence, at a minimum, `n` will need to be very large.

As mentioned by @user3386109, "error in the result is bounded by 1 / (2n+1)", so about 5e14 iterations will be needed.  (Rough estimate: 10 days on my PC.) As typical `double` has a precision of about 1 part in pow(2,53) or 1 in 9e15, the limits of `double` calculation are being reached.  The below code compares the order of calculation to reduce error, but *at best*, the error will still be at least 0.5 parts in 9e15.

As the terms of the series oscillate about the limit, when stopping after `n` iterations, a final iteration of 1/2 the next iteration could be added.  this would gain about 1 bit of accuracy.

As others have mentioned, other methods exist to calculate π that converge faster.

---

Updated per the good observation by @user3386109.

In summing the terms, code can sum them in various orders.  The 2 below methods illustrate that a modestly more stable result is achieved earlier when summing the small terms together first.  I`d expect at best only a 1 or 2 bit better answer.

This was re-done using `float` as the small improvement does not show up until the last few bits are stable.  With `double` and this slowly convergent series, that would take too long.

```
//Leibniz formula for pi/4
typedef float fp;

fp LeibnizForward(unsigned n) {
  volatile fp sum = 0.0;
  fp sign = 1.0;
  unsigned i = 1;
  while (n-- > 0) {
    sum += sign / i;
    sign = -sign;
    i = (i + 2);
  }
  return sum;
}

fp LeibnizReverse(unsigned n) {
  volatile fp sum = 0.0;
  fp sign = 1.0;
  unsigned i = 2 * n - 1;
  if (n % 2 == 0)
    sign = -sign;
  while (n-- > 0) {
    sum += sign / i;
    sign = -sign;
    i = (i - 2);
  }
  return sum;
}

void PiTest(unsigned n) {
  printf("%u\n", n);
  static const fp pic = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795;
  const char *format = "%s %0.9f\n";
  printf(format, "pi-", nextafterf(pic,0));
  printf(format, "pi ", pic);
  printf(format, "pi+", nextafterf(pic,4));
  fp pif = LeibnizForward(n) * 4;
  printf(format, "pif", pif);
  fflush(stdout);
  fp pir = LeibnizReverse(n) * 4;
  printf(format, "pir", pir);
  fflush(stdout);
}

int main(void) {
  PiTest(0);
  PiTest(1);
  PiTest(10);
  PiTest(100);
  PiTest(1000);
  PiTest(10000);
  PiTest(100000);
  PiTest(1000000);
  PiTest(10000000);
  PiTest(100000000);

  return 0;
}

0
pi- 3.141592503
pi  3.141592741
pi+ 3.141592979
pif 0.000000000
pir 0.000000000
1
pi- 3.141592503
pi  3.141592741
pi+ 3.141592979
pif 4.000000000
pir 4.000000000
10
pi- 3.141592503
pi  3.141592741
pi+ 3.141592979
pif 3.041839600
pir 3.041839600
25
pi- 3.141592503
pi  3.141592741
pi+ 3.141592979
pif 3.181576490
pir 3.181576729
100
pi- 3.141592503
pi  3.141592741
pi+ 3.141592979
pif 3.131592512
pir 3.131592751
1000
pi- 3.14 1592503
pi  3.14 1592741
pi+ 3.14 1592979
pif 3.14 0592575
pir 3.14 0592575
10000
pi- 3.141 592503
pi  3.141 592741
pi+ 3.141 592979
pif 3.141 498566
pir 3.141 492605
100000
pi- 3.1415 92503
pi  3.1415 92741
pi+ 3.1415 92979
pif 3.1415 85827
pir 3.1415 82489
1000000
pi- 3.14159 2503
pi  3.14159 2741
pi+ 3.14159 2979
pif 3.14159 5364
pir 3.14159 1549
10000000
pi- 3.14159 2503 previous float
pi  3.14159 2741 machine float pi
pi+ 3.14159 2979 next float
pif 3.14159 6794
pir 3.14159 2503
100000000 Additional iterations do not improve the result.
pi- 3.14159 2503
pi  3.14159 2741 
pi+ 3.14159 2979
pif 3.14159 6794
pir 3.14159 2503
1000000000
pi- 3.14159 2503
pi  3.14159 2741
pi+ 3.14159 2979
pif 3.14159 6794
pir 3.14159 2503
```

Comment: The arrows seem to indicate that you think the answer is correct. However, note for example with n=100000 you have pi=3.14159 but with reverse Leibniz, the answer is 3.14158

Comment: Could you explain in two words the reason of such difference?
I suppose it's all because of specific representation of `float-pointing` variables in memory, but don't sure in it..

Comment: @Yulian Khlevnoy No - not in 2 words.  The effect is small yet measurable.  This slowly converging series has other issues though that swamp the effect I was attempting to show.

Comment: @chux, it seems to be very interesting case. Can you give several links or something else that will help to understand that effect?

Comment: @Yulian Khlevnoy Here is 1: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6699066/in-which-order-should-floats-be-added-to-get-the-most-precise-result and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

Change your `printf` statement to print more of the values after the decimal point.

As an example, using

```
printf("%30.28Lf\n",s);
```

will print the number to 28 places after the decimal point. With `n=25`, I got the following output.

```
0.7953941713587578038252220991
```

Comment: Which is still a very poor approximation to π/4.

Comment: The error in the result is bounded by `1 / (2n+1)`. So to get a result accurate to 15 decimal places, you would need `n=10^15`. But if you did that, the accumulated rounding errors would invalidate the answer. The Leibniz formula just flat out cannot be used to calculate a result accurate to 15 decimal places.