# How to extract digits of irrational numbers one by one in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, numbers, digits, arbitrary-precision

I'm trying to read digits of irrational numbers such as `2^0.5` and `pi` one by one in Matlab.
I tried using this:

```
x=pi;
y=num2str(x)
out=str2num(y(1))
```

but it only reads just a few digits. Then I tried using vpa function.

```
x=vpa(pi,100);
y=num2str(x)
out=str2num(y(1))
```

but vpa makes x a sym variable which num2str can't read.

Then I tried the method explained in [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/59178-sum-digits-of-big-numbers#answer_71632), but it only seems to work for rational numbers since

```
sym(99)^95
```

returns a number which can be read digit by digit using

```
char(sym(99)^95)-'0'
```

but

```
sym(2)^0.5
```

just says

```
ans= 2^(1/2)
```

How can I do the same with irrational numbers to say 10000 digits of precision and store these digits in a (1000,1) array?

Comment: That is very very non-trivial for large decimals, you definitely need symbolic math. Generally speaking, people propose infinite series that converge to the number at hand and compute it in parts (as partly explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/297/simple-numerical-methods-for-calculating-the-digits-of-pi))

Comment: @AnderBiguri It is a method I thought of at first but I need exact digits in this range. even a +-1 uncertainty in the 10000th digit would not work.

Comment: This type of methods have been used to compute **trillions** of digits.

Comment: To be more precise, 42*10^8 digits of Pi: http://www.super-computing.org/pi_current.html . This page shows the current 2nd world record of computations of Pi.

Comment: @AnderBiguri That would work. So I'll try using char(sym(1-1/3+1/5-1/7+1/9-1/11+...)-'0') to get close to digits of pi/4.

Comment: let me be clearer than my previous comments: The 2nd world record used code 78000 lines long to be able to do this accurately. Your problem is not a simple problem, its an entire research project. You can not "just ask it in the internet"

Comment: @AnderBiguri Well I thought of it as a "programming issue for which there is a rather simple solution because doing the same for 99^95 is simple" and maybe I was wrong. How did I found out? by "asking on the internet".

Comment: Apologies, I did not mean to be rude, but informative. Just letting you know you have a bigger problem than you think you had! ;)

Comment: Even more interesting for you, the world record holder in 2013 explains a bit further how they did it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14283270/how-do-i-determine-whether-my-calculation-of-pi-is-accurate

Comment: @AnderBiguri It was really helpful. Actually, I was trying to do a small project of numerology for my own curiosity. Seems it is harder than what I thought. Thank you.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Note that there are some relatively simple algorithms to compute the digit-by-digit decimal value of square roots, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Digit-by-digit_calculation). Your point stands, but 78,000 lines of code is definitely not needed if you limit the problem to, for example, square roots. A [Project Euler question](https://projecteuler.net/problem=80) asks for arbitrary precision calcs of root 2, for which many solutions can be found online (e.g. [here](https://blog.dreamshire.com/project-euler-80-solution/))