# Error in π Approximation Causing Divergence on 29th Digit

Tags: java, function, math, precision

I have a π approximation program that I've been working on. It uses the Rananujen-Chudnovsky series(https://stackoverflow.com/a/531/2058221) to approximate π. I test the number generated by having 2 variants of π statically loaded in memory from different sources which I test against. The empirical version that I compute consistently fails to get the number correct past 29 digits for some reason. I've used the `MathContext` on just about everything I possibly can use it on. NOTE: `broadcastSystemMessage()` is essentially a `System.out.println()` but makes the formatting "nice", essentially think of the first argument as the title + : and the second as the body.

Algorithm Implementation:

```
/**
     * The much faster Ramanujan-Chudnovsky algorithm.
     */
    RAMANUJAN_CHUDNOVSKY {

                private final long k1 = 545140134, k2 = 13591409, k3 = 640320,
                k4 = 100100025, k5 = 327843840, k6 = 53360;

                @Override
                public String getAlgorithmName() {
                    return "Ramanujan-Chudnovsky";
                }

                @Override
                public String getAlgorithmFormula() {
                    return "S=Σ from 0 to ∞(-1^n *(6n)! * (k2 + n * k1) / ((n!) ^ 3 * (3n)! * 8 * k4 * k5) ^ n)"
                    + "π = k6 * sqrt(k3) / S";
                }

                @Override
                public BigDecimal initCalculation(long iterations, long significantDigits) {
                    //God, if you're real, please forgive me for this; Java didn't give me a choice.
                    MathContext context = new MathContext((int) significantDigits);
                    BigDecimal s = new BigDecimal(0, context);
                    for (int n = 0; n < iterations; n++) {
                        s = s.add(new BigDecimal(Math.pow(-1, n), context).multiply(new BigDecimal(factorial(6 * n), context), context)
                                .multiply(new BigDecimal(BigInteger.valueOf(k2).add(BigInteger.valueOf(n).multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(k1))),
                                                context), context).divide(new BigDecimal(factorial(n).pow(3), context).multiply(
                                                new BigDecimal(factorial(new BigDecimal(3 * n, context).toBigInteger()), context), context)
                                        .multiply(new BigDecimal(BigInteger.valueOf(8).multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(k4))
                                                        .multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(k5)), context), context).pow(n, context), context), context);
                    }
                    Main.brodcastSystemMessage("Check", k6 + " || + " + k3 + " || " + sqrt(new BigDecimal(k3, context), context));
                    return new BigDecimal(k6, context).multiply(sqrt(new BigDecimal(k3, context), context),
                            context).divide(s, context);
                    //Square Root of k3 approximation: 800.19997500624804755833750301086
                }
            }
```

π:

```
public static final BigDecimal π = new BigDecimal("3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628620899862803482534211706798214808651328230664709384460955058223172535940812848111745028410270193852110555964462294895493038196442881097566593344612847564823378678316527120190914564856692346034861045432664821339360726024914127372458700660631558817488152092096282925409171536436789259036001133053054882046652138414695194151160943305727036575959195309218611738193261179310511854807446237996274956735188575272489122793818301194912983367336244065664308602139494639522473719070217986094370277053921717629317675238467481846766940513200056812714526356082778577134275778960917363717872146844090122495343014654958537105079227968925892354201995611212902196086403441815981362977477130996051870721134999999837297804995105973173281609631859502445945534690830264252230825334468503526193118817101000313783875288658753320838142061717766914730359825349042875546873115956286388235378759375195778185778053217122680661300192787661119590921642019893809525720106548586327886593615338182796823030195203530185296899577362259941389124972177528347913151557485724245415069595082953311686172785588907509838175463746493931925506040092770167113900984882401285836160356370766010471018194295559619894676783744944825537977472684710404753464620804668425906949129331367702898915210475216205696602405803815019351125338243003558764024749647326391419927260426992279678235478163600934172164121992458631503028618297455570674983850549458858692699569092721079750930295532116534498720275596023648066549911988183479775356636980742654252786255181841757467289097777279380008164706001614524919217321721477235014144197356854816136115735255213347574184946843852332390739414333454776241686251898356948556209921922218427255025425688767179049460165346680498862723279178608578438382796797668145410095388378636095068006422512520511739298489608412848862694560424196528502221066118630674427862203919494504712371378696095636437191728746776465757396241389086583264599581339");
```

Calling Method:

```
BigDecimal π = PIAlgorithms.RAMANUJAN_CHUDNOVSKY.initCalculation(10,
            1000);
    brodcastSystemMessage("π Calculation Result", π + "");
    brodcastSystemMessage("", StringUtils.getCommonPrefix(π.toPlainString(), PIAlgorithms.π.toPlainString()).length() + "");
```

Misc. Functions Used in Algorithm:

```
/**
 * Custom factorial function.
 *
 * @param integer The integer to use
 * @return The factorial of the number
 */
private static BigInteger factorial(int integer) {
    return factorial(BigInteger.valueOf(integer));
}

/**
 * Custom factorial function.
 *
 * @param integer The integer to use
 * @return The factorial of the number
 */
private static BigInteger factorial(@NotNull BigInteger integer) {
    if (integer.equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
        return BigInteger.ONE;
    } else if (integer.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't take the factorial of a number less than zero");
    }
    BigInteger i = integer.equals(BigInteger.ONE) ? integer : integer.multiply(factorial(integer.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)));
    System.out.println(integer + "! --> " + i);
    return i;
} 
private static BigDecimal sqrt(BigDecimal number, MathContext context) {
    BigDecimal first = new BigDecimal("0", context);
    BigDecimal second = new BigDecimal(Math.sqrt(number.doubleValue()), context);
    while (!first.equals(second)) {
        first = second;
        second = number.divide(first, context);
        second = second.add(first, context);
        second = second.divide(new BigDecimal("2"), context);

    }
    return second;
}
```

Edit:
First 5 Terms: 3.141592653589793238462643383587297242678
First 10 Terms: 3.141592653589793238462643383587297242678
First 15 Terms: 3.141592653589793238462643383587297242678
Comparison<π>: 3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628

Comment: So, how many terms do you use, and what incorrect value do you get? How accurate is your BigDecimal sqrt?

Comment: @DouglasZare Not sure what you mean by terms, but if you mean iterations, then as many as you want. It still gives PI to 29 digits and no more regardless of iterations for some reason.

Comment: Terms means the numbers you are adding. It is unusual to call terms iterations. Can you state the first 40 decimal places you are getting after 5, 10, and 15 terms?

Comment: @DouglasZare Added terms & π for comparison.

Comment: Ok, this is one of those series where you get about 15 digits per term. So, instead of the values after 5, 10, and 15 terms, which appear equal, you should look at the values after 1, 2, or 3 terms. At least one of those terms is wrong, since the formula is correct and in a separate implementation I got the correct first 40 decimal digits.

Comment: After Robert Dodier's answer, I should clarify that I thought there were imbalanced parentheses and corrected the formula to include (8 * k4 * k5) ^ n. I used Sum[(-1)^i (6 i)! (k2 + i k1)/((i!)^3 (3 i)! (8 k4 k5)^i), {i, 0, n}] in Mathematica.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you've copied the formula incorrectly. I assume that your code implements the formula shown in `getAlgorithmFormula`. That formula differs from the one shown in the reference -- the parentheses for the denominator of the summand are incorrect.

In this output from Maxima, `g` is your formula and `g2` is the correct formula:

```
(%i118) g(N);
          N - 1
          ====                                n
          \     (545140134 n + 13591409) (- 1)  (6 n)!
           >    --------------------------------------
          /                         n   3 n       n
          ====    262537412640768000  n!    (3 n)!
          n = 0
(%o118)   --------------------------------------------
                       426880 sqrt(10005)
(%i119) g2(N);
          N - 1
          ====                                n
          \     (545140134 n + 13591409) (- 1)  (6 n)!
           >    --------------------------------------
          /                           n   3
          ====      262537412640768000  n!  (3 n)!
          n = 0
(%o119)   --------------------------------------------
                       426880 sqrt(10005)
```

Your formula has the first 2 terms correct (n = 0 and n = 1). These 2 are enough to give you 28 digits correct. From then on (n >= 2) the terms are incorrect, so you are stuck with 28 digits.

Is it necessary to use Java? It is pretty clumsy to handle arbitrary precision numbers. I know [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net) can handle that pretty easily, and I'm sure there are other packages too.

Comment: Wow, I fixed the position of the `pow` and it worked nicely! Thanks! Also, I never really considered using anything else other than Java considering it's the only language I know currently. I know I can use it through `JNI` though.

Comment: @SarahSzabo I'm glad to hear you got it working. I recommend some programming environment other than Java if you are interested in problems such as this. Aside from Maxima, you can try [Sympy](http://sympy.org) and [Sage](http://sagemath.org). These latter two are based on Python which is probably easy for you since you already know Java. Good luck and have fun.