# Approximate pi with rational numbers

Tags: algorithm, math, algebra, approximation

The value of pi = 3.1415926535... can approximate pi with rational numbers like this:

- 22/7 = 3.142857142857...
- 355/113 = 3.141592920353...

I want to construct more accurate fractions, so:
Please tell me the fast algorithm of finding integers `p, q (1 <= q <= n)` such `p/q` is nearest to pi.

I only have a brute-force algorithm and it takes `O(n)` to find it, so it is slow for `n <= 10^12`.

Do you have any efficient algorithm?

EDIT:
Different from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-get-the-value-of-%CF%80) because I already know the value of pi and I only want to construct the most accurate fraction that denominator is less or equal to n.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-get-the-value-of-%CF%80

Comment: See http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/06/30/all-rational-approximations-of-pi-are-useless/

Comment: @PascalDescollonges please read my question.

Comment: @Mankarse I read this before asking question, but there is not written ALGORITHM of finding them.

Comment: Look at jon-hanson and nulcaroni's answers. They both have algorithms.

Comment: @PascalDescollonges But it includes irrational numbers.

Comment: Look at the first algorithm in nlucaroni's answer. I do not see any irrationals.

Comment: @PascalDescollonges Look at my question. You are given an integer n, and you have to find the fraction that denominator <= n. So, if n=100, the answer is p=311 and q=99 because it is nearest for all over p, q such that 1 <= q <= n.

Comment: There are lists and formulae available here: http://oeis.org/search?q=convergents+to+pi