# Splitting Python MeshGrid Into Cells

Tags: python, numpy, geometry, simulation, computational-geometry

**Problem Statement**

Need to split an N-Dimensional MeshGrid into "cubes":

Ex)
2-D Case:

(-1,1) |(0,1) |(1,1)

(-1,0) |(0,0) |(1,0)

(-1,-1)|(0,-1)|(1,-1)

There will be 4 cells, each with 2^D points:

I want to be able to process the mesh, placing the coordinate points of each cell into a container to do further processing.

```
Cells =   [{(-1,1) (0,1)(-1,0),(0,0)},

          {(0,1),(1,1),(0,0),(1,0)},

          {(-1,0),(0,0)(-1,-1),(0,-1)}

          {(0,0),(1,0)(0,-1),(1,-1)}]
```

I use the following to generate the mesh for an arbitrary dimension d:

```
grid = [np.linspace(-1.0 , 1.0, num = K+1) for i in range(d)]
res_to_unpack = np.meshgrid(*grid,indexing = 'ij')
```

Which has output:

```
[array([[-1., -1., -1.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 1.,  1.,  1.]]), array([[-1.,  0.,  1.],
   [-1.,  0.,  1.],
   [-1.,  0.,  1.]])]
```

So I want to be able to generate the above cells container for a given D dimensional mesh grid. Split on a given K that is a power of 2.

I need this container so for each cell, I need to reference all 2^D points associated and calculate the distance from an origin.

**Edit For Clarification**

K should partition the grid into K ** D number of cells, with (K+1) ** D points. Each Cell should have 2 ** D number of points. Each "cell" will have volume (2/K)^D.

So for K = 4, D = 2

```
Cells = [ {(-1,1),(-0.5,1),(-1,0.5),(-0.5,0.5)},
          {(-0.5,1),(-0.5,0.5)(0.0,1.0),(0,0.5)},
            ...
          {(0.0,-0.5),(0.5,-0.5),(0.0,-1.0),(0.5,-1.0)},
          {(0.5,-1.0),(0.5,-1.0),(1.0,-0.5),(1.0,-1.0)}]
```

This is output for TopLeft, TopLeft + Right Over, Bottom Left, Bottom Left + Over Left. There will we 16 cells in this set, each with four coordinates each. For increasing K, say K = 8. There will be 64 cells, each with four points.

Comment: How is this different from [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53643716/splitting-a-grid-into-cubes-hypercube)?

Comment: I thought I would be more specific.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should give you what you need:

```
from itertools import product
import numpy as np

def splitcubes(K, d):
    coords = [np.linspace(-1.0 , 1.0, num=K + 1) for i in range(d)]
    grid = np.stack(np.meshgrid(*coords)).T

    ks = list(range(1, K))
    for slices in product(*([[slice(b,e) for b,e in zip([None] + ks, [k+1 for k in ks] + [None])]]*d)):
        yield grid[slices]

def cubesets(K, d):
    if (K & (K - 1)) or K < 2:
        raise ValueError('K must be a positive power of 2. K: %s' % K)

    return [set(tuple(p.tolist()) for p in c.reshape(-1, d)) for c in splitcubes(K, d)]
```

## Demonstration of 2D case

Here's a little demonstration of the 2D case:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def assemblecube(c, spread=.03):
    c = np.array(list(c))
    c = c[np.lexsort(c.T[::-1])]

    d = int(np.log2(c.size))
    for i in range(d):
        c[2**i:2**i + 2] = c[2**i + 1:2**i - 1:-1]

    # get the point farthest from the origin
    sp = c[np.argmax((c**2).sum(axis=1)**.5)]
    # shift all points a small distance towards that farthest point
    c += sp * .1 #np.copysign(np.ones(sp.size)*spread, sp)

    # create several different orderings of the same points so that matplotlib will draw a closed shape
    return [(np.roll(c, i, axis=1) - (np.roll(c, i, axis=1)[0] - c[0])[None,:]).T for i in range(d)]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
ax = fig.gca()

for i,c in enumerate(cubesets(4, 2)):
    for cdata in assemblecube(c):
        p = ax.plot(*cdata, c='C%d' % (i % 9))

ax.set_aspect('equal', 'box')
fig.show()
```

Output:

[image]

The cubes have been shifted slightly apart for visualization purposes (so they don't overlap and cover each other up).

## Demonstration of 3D case

Here's the same thing for the 3D case:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

for i,c in enumerate(cubesets(2,3)):
    for cdata in assemblecube(c, spread=.05):
        ax.plot(*cdata, c=('C%d' % (i % 9)))

plt.gcf().gca().set_aspect('equal', 'box')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

## Demonstration for `K=4`

Here's the output for the same 2D and 3D demonstrations as above, but with `K=4`:

[image]

[image]

Comment: If the answer solves your problem, you should [mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: I wanted to clarify one point, in the case when K>2, say K = 4. The output is a list of 4 sets each containing 9 points each. Though, each cell should still only contain four points.

Comment: In that case, I don't really understand what you want the `K` parameter to do. How should the output change for `K=4` vs `K=2`? If you want me to be able to show you how to implement it correctly, you'll have to add an example for `K=4` to the end of your question, including the desired output.

Comment: I posted an edit, I really appreciate the help, I apologize if the problem was the specific enough. I was trying to edit your solution though I am new to python so I am struggling.

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect the updates to the definition of `K` in your question.

Comment: Thank you for the answer this works perfectly. Though is there any way to make this faster? I need 4 digits of precision in my answer, and for increasing K it is running extremely slow. For K > 4096 it is taking hours and my computer is running out of application memory, to compute pi to four digits of precision.

Comment: "doctor, doctor! It hurts when I do this..." Maybe consider using one of the [actually good ways to calculate pi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/531/425458), instead of trying to reinvent the [pebble game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pebble_game)?